# How to create a 'Pair' table in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio connected to SQL Server 2008 R2.

- I have a table called `User` with a column `Id` (`uniqueidentifier`)
- I have a table called `Role` with a column `Id` (`uniqueidentifier`)
- I want a table called `UserRolePair` with 2 columns: `UserId` and `RoleId`.

I need each row to be unique (no duplicate roles for each user).

This is easy - I just right-click, choose `Indexes & Keys` and create a new **unique** key, that is comprised of both columns.

Now what I need to do - is to create a foreign key from `UserId` to the `Id` column of the `User` table, and create a foreign key from `RoleId` to the `Id` column of the `Role` table.

But when I choose `Relationships` from the sub-menu - I get this:

[image: this1]

First of all - why do I have 2 relationships here ??

Second of all - when I want to create a new foreign key now for each column **separately** I get this:

[image: this2]

I can't choose to `RoleId` the `Id` column of the `Role` table !

It says I need to assign both columns of `UserRole` table with foreign keys **from the same table**.

What is the solution ?

Is the 'unique' what's causing my problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use T-SQL statements instead of struggling with the visual designers.

a) create foreign key from `UserRolePair` to `Role`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserRolePair
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserRolePair_Role
FOREIGN KEY (RoleID) REFERENCES dbo.Role(ID)
```

b) create foreign key from `UserRolePair` to `User`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserRolePair
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserRolePair_User
FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES dbo.User(ID)
```

Just execute those in a query window (make sure to be in the right database!) and you're done!

Comment: Thanks ! I'll check it and repost if needed